# Как добавить класс элементу исходя из локации пользователя на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как мне добавить класс элементу `li` (родитель с классом `parent` ), **только при условии** что пользователь находиться на странице, в данном случае *сувениры* или на страницах дочерних ссылок (вложенный `ul`), а при переходе на другие страницы класс удалялся, 2 часа ломаю голову, не могу понять как реализовать.
Вот html:

```
 <li class="item-176 deeper parent">
        <a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry">Сувениры</a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li class="item-177"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/ruchki">Ручки</a></li>
        <li class="item-178"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/magnity">Магниты</a></li>
        <li class="item-181"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/fleshki">Флешки</a></li>
        <li class="item-182"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/posuda">Посуда</a></li>
        <li class="item-183"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/chasy">Часы</a></li>
        <li class="item-184"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/zonty">Зонты</a></li>
        <li class="item-185"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/futbolki-kepki">Футболки/кепки</a></li>
        <li class="item-186"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/pledy-podushki">Пледы/подушки</a></li>
        <li class="item-187"><a href="/korporativnaya-reklama/suveniry/chto-to-neobychnoe">Что-то необычное</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
```

Вот jquery, который добавляет класс текущему элементу, как прописать тут нужное мне условие?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.nav11 li').each(function () 
                {
                    if (this.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href == location.href) 
                        this.className = "active";
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     if(/suveniry/.test(location.href))
            jQuery('.nav11 li').each(function () 
                {
                    if (this.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href == location.href) 
                        this.className = "active";
                });
            });
```